# Fail to refresh jquery mobile listview after item added by ngClick

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

I am trying to add item into listview of jquery mobile dynamically. I add item using a ngClick event and show list using ngRepeat. I have called listview refresh but the latest item cannot style properly. Which event should I use to refresh properly? Thanks.

```
$scope.addItem = function () {
    $scope.userList.push($scope.userInputText);
    $scope.userInputText = null;
    $("#listview1").listview("refresh");
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hFj2T/

Answer (score 3):

The following directive works for me.  Just add list-view to your ul tag and also the data-watch="userList" to tell angular which object to watch for changes.

```
<ul list-view data-watch="userList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" >
   <li ng-repeat="user in userList">{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>

app.directive('listView', function () {
  var link=function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $(element).listview();
    scope.$watchCollection(attrs.watch, function() {
      $(element).listview("refresh");
    });
  };
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope:false,
    link: link
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me. For anyone struggling to get this working I had to make sure my list was not in a div with data-role="controlgroup" and also make sure to set data-watch correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
Give a timeout for styling the list view:

 $scope.addItem = function () {

        $scope.userList.push($scope.userInputText);
        $scope.userInputText = null; 

        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#listview1").listview("refresh");
        },100);
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this in a new fiddle. It works but I want to know if there is any better event that I can do this refresh. http://jsfiddle.net/hFj2T/4/

Comment: I have not used angular.js but used jquerymobile, in JQM this does not happen and refresh works instantly, not sure why it does not work out in this case!!!

Comment: My guess is AngularJS didn't update the list yet when the refresh is called. These 2 frameworks are not aware of the work of the other party.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because both JQuery UI and Angular are attempting to update the DOM using the document ready event.  A race condition is occurring in which Angular is adding the new data after JQuery has already created the listview.  Sheetal's solution works because it forces JQuery to modify the DOM and create the listview *after* Angular has populated the data.

Another solution is a tool aptly called the [jquery mobile angular adapter](https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter)